# Android accelerometer accuracy

Tags: android

Android Sensor Listener is reading accelerometer data in float with up to 6 or 7 decimal points.I don't need that kind of accuracy.Is there a way to read just till 1 or 2 decimal points and decrease the overhead.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this...if the value is never lower than 6th to the decimal point....it will return the value to 2nd of the decimal point

```
(float)Math.Round(value * 10000) / 10000
```